# PHP Puts data to MySQL æøå with?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I have tried everything. When i submit data from my website (POST) to MySQL it automaticly puts "æ" to ??? and å to ??? and ø to ???

In the top of my website (where i put the data):

`include("../connection.php");
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

And the form:
`<form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">`

The data is still æ => ???, å => ???, ø => ???

What to do?

Comment: Your table is probably created with wrong charset.

Comment: So what is the correct charset?

Comment: Correct charset is UTF-8, as you are using that in your code. But when you originally created your table, you probably did not specify UTF-8.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Do not use the antiquated `mysql_*` interface.  Are you getting _exactly three_ question marks?  (I would expect one or two.)